# If object has a value that contains text

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I am trying to see if any properties in an object contain a value. So far all things that I have tried have given the error `TypeError: undefined is not a function`

```
for (var prop in obj) {
                var objProp= obj[prop];
                var testone = obj.indexOfPropertyValue(prop,query);
                var testtwo= obj[prop].indexOf(query);
                var testthree = objProp.indexOf(query);
            }
```

Comment: The console gives 'TypeError: undefined is not a function' when it tries to run any of what I have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not everything has an indexOf method.

So check to see property is a string before working with it

```
for (var prop in obj) {
  if( obj.hasOwnProperty( prop ) && typeof obj[prop] === "string") {
      console.log(obj[prop].indexOf(query));
  }
}
```

or you can check to see if it supports indexOf

```
if( obj.hasOwnProperty( prop ) && obj[prop].indexOf)
```

Comment: That worked. Cant believe I didn't think of doing something like that.